# Not able to run protractor on angularjs website

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am running a website which is based on Angularjs - https://dev.wooter.co/

When I open it manually, it opens correctly.. But when I open it through automation, it just opens the browser and nothing loads.. Due to which my test-case fails..

```
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at ontimeout (timers.js:380:14)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:244:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

spec.js

```
describe('Woter Test', function() {
 it('should add a Name as WOOTER | Home', function(done) {
  browser.get('https://dev.wooter.co/');
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toBe('Wooter | Home');
    element(by.xpath("//a[@aria-label='SIGN IN']")).click();
  //var guru= element(by.xpath('html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/h3'));
  //expect(guru.getText()).toEqual('Hello change GURU99!');
  });
});
```

conf.js -

```
exports.config = {




    capabilities: {
        "browserName": "chrome",
       // "chromeOptions": {
         //   binary: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
           // args: [],
            //extensions: [],
       // }
    },
      seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

      onPrepare: function() {
        var width = 1600;
        var height = 1200;
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
    },
      specs: ['C:/Users/Desktop/spec.js'],
    };
```

Comment: Your website took a really long time to load on my browser. You probably need to increase the default test timeout. Add this right after the `describe` line: `this.timeout(50000)`